# Installing Jenkins on Heroku

Tags: heroku, jenkins

Currently I have Jenkins installed in my laptop and works fine. I am to move this setup to cloud. My client has bought Heroku license and was considering using Heroku space n license to install Jenkins. How to install Jenkins on Heroku?

Answer (score 5):

I have tried installing  Jenkins and mostly because of free account restrictions I was not getting enough RAM to install jenkins on Heroku.
Free account can give only 512MB ram which is not sufficient for jenkins.

Here is my thought: Don't use heroku for jenkins.
Why : Because file system of heroku is ephemeral that means that there is no guarantee that data created by jenkins will be persisted. If you want to try that with your clients paid account (hopefully you have enough ram) then you can try installing jenkins on heroku via docker.

So basically you need to create a docker image and push that on heroku.

If you really want to push jenkins to cloud then you can use amazon's elastic beanstalk cloud service to get an instance and install jenkins there (again you need to go via docker route.)

Here is the url for the jenkins which I have installed on free account of amazon's elastic beanstalk: http://sample-env-1.ddewedk82g.us-east-2.elasticbeanstalk.com/login?from=%2F

I hope this explanation helps!!

Comment: This is correct - Jenkins is not well-suited to Heroku as it is not designed as a 12 Factor app: https://12factor.net/